Can this C++ template be simplified with a C MACRO?
I have a template class with a read() method. It needs to call a C functions: read1(), read2(), read3() etc based upon the template parameter value. Is there is a cleaner way to do this than a switch on the template value? I have tried using a MACRO:
#define READ(N) read##N##()

But this doesn't work as X is simply replaced by the C Preprocessor as 'N' resulting in "readN()"
int read1()
{
}

int read2()
{
}

int read3()
{
}

...

template <int N>
struct Reader
{
    int read()
    {
        switch (N)
        {
        case 1:
            return read1();
        case 2:
            return read2();
        case 3:
            return read3();
        }
    }

    /* Doesn't work as X is simply replaced by the C Preprocessor as 'N' resulting in "readN()"
    #define READ(X) read##X##()
    int read()
    {
        return READ(N);
    }
    */
};




A side note: you can use if constexpr instead of a switch to resolve the required call at compile time.

Avoid using macros especially with modern c++. Just use constexpr if etc that modern c++ provides.

macro would not work here, because they are resolved before compiling, but several patterns might. How many options are there? Several? Alot?

@user12002570 I agree macros are bad. But the dupe is not really relevant. I think the OP would like to avoid having to specify all the read options separately (see the example in the code under the /* ... */ comment). This is why I wrote my comment above related to if constexpr as a side-note.

The whole idea of using templates is to avoid macros. I also fail to see the benefit of using either templates or macros in this code. Why don't you call read1, read2, read3 explicitly without all the boiler plate? (Probably the example is over-simplified in this case)

@PepijnKramer it might be some labor contractions before re-inventing a Visitor pattern with compile-time features.

How about specialization: template <int N>int read(); template <> int read<1>() {return read1();}?

The set of available readNNN() functions cannot be unbounded, because each one must be written by someone. Therefore, it is feasible to enumerate them in the read() function.

@j6t It's possible that they were preexisting legacy code. Some handlers or something. I had a case where they were generated (protobuf structures as source+ additional output code generator ). About 120+ different structures. That's where a generated lookup table came in as well, dyamic dyspatch in my case though (because pbuf is virtual interface).

One can

use if constexpr instead of switch to select proper read call:

use constexpr lookup table, for neatness.

use, if desperate, constexpr implementation of map, but standard ISO one is too generic and cannot be constexpr. A map is more useful for run-time dispatching.

wrap functions into specializations of a template function, if there are only few.


Lookup table as a function pointer table:
#include <iostream>

int read1(){ return 1; }
int read2(){ return 2; }
int read3(){ return 3; }

template <int N>
struct Reader
{
    static constexpr int (*read_functions[])(void) = {
      nullptr, 
      read1,
      read2,
      read3,
    };

    static_assert(N > 0 && N < std::size(read_functions));
    int read() {
        return read_functions[N]();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Reader<3> r;
    std::cout << "Read " << r.read();
}

See on godbolt. Note, with -O2 it's completely optimized out.

Thanks - that's the trick I was looking for! The C++ class I am implementing is a wrapper class for a PIC32 C driver. The UART functions are UARTx_Read, UARTx_ReadCountGet, UARTx_Write, UARTx_WriteCountGet etc. The code is exactly the same for each UART on the PIC (6 in total), so I thought it would nice to implement it as a template class based on UART index. I am glad to remove use of MACROs.

@pic32cpp as i understand the difference between functions are mainly register numbers? You can go further and have ONE function template per operation but have templates of these constants.
